# Using SQLAlchemy (MySQL) in Azure Function App

Tags: python, azure, sqlalchemy

I am new to Azure and am trying to migrate some worker scripts to Azure Functions from Heroku.

I have been stuck for a few days with a problem that functions weren’t showing after deploying my function app to Azure. The function app ran perfectly locally.

After a day of debugging to try to identify which bit of code was stopping the functions from appearing (there were no error messages), I have identified the culprit as the bit in the `try` block:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
import os
import logging
 
DATABASE_URL = os.environ['DATABASE_URL']
try:
    engine = create_engine(DATABASE_URL)
    Session = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)
    session = Session()
except Exception as e:
    logging.error("Error creating database connection")
    logging.error(e)
 
Base = declarative_base()
```

Does anybody know what could be causing this? All of the imports are in `requirements.txt`. The env variable is set correctly on Azure.

Comment: If the try block is stopping the code, you should see the error in the log file.

Comment: That try block won't stop the program. It will log the error, then continue with the rest of the script. Which is probably not what you want, if the rest of the script needs the SQLAlchemy session.

Comment: @Barmar I added the try block as a temporary measure during debugging, to try to throw something to the logs. Maybe I’m looking at the wrong logs on Azure, as I see nothing?

Comment: I don't know much about Azure, so I don't know where it would log by default.

Answer (score 0):

After a call with Microsoft's technical support, they showed me how to raise the relevant logs in the Azure portal (the ones for when functions are not being registered).

This revealed the cause of the issue to be a module not importing correctly from `mysqlclient`. I switched to `PyMySQL` and this worked instead.

I believe the cause of this issue is that `mysqlclient` uses some non-Python code that Azure doesn't support, whereas `PyMySQL` is pure Python.